# How to install and integrate j2me polish in netbeans ide 7.1.2?

Tags: java-me, j2mepolish

I have tried to install j2me polish to my IDE ,but I am not able to get,initially I have downloaded j2me polish 2.0.7.jar,I have used the command  "java -jar j2mepolish-2.0.7.jar"

C:\Documents and Settings\pavan\My Documents\Downloads>java -jar j2mepolish-2.0.
7.jar;

It saying unable to acces jar file,can any one having steps to install and run sample j2me polish application?For this can I have to install j2me polish plugin?

Comment: is your JAVA_HOME path working ? i mean when you fire `javac` on command line, it is `command not found` error or `javac - options` ?

Comment: Hi,i have installed J2ME-Polish2.1.4 and netbeans j2me plugin ,after that i restared the ide,then i start creating j2me polish project,i eneterd project name and i clicked next button on ide,it is saying Unable to read selected devices - check your J2ME Polish installation. You will ‌​need at least J2ME Polish 2. ? Can i run j2me polish apps on Nokia Symbian Belle SdK 1.0 devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I follow the following steps and it works for me all the time. Download J2ME-Polish2.1.4, install the library and also Netbeans plugin. Perhaps you will need to restart the IDE. Now

1) Create a project (for example Polish Table) in Netbeans, making use of J2ME polish plugin. Let's call it

2) Copy all files except nbproject directory in /samples/tableitem/ to NetBeans directory. Override build.xml created by Netbeans during this copying process.

3) Copy contents of /samples/tableitem/nbproject (except private folder) to directory. Override all the files.

4) Switch to NetBeans directory

5)Edit project.xml file. Comment out tag. Rename project name in tag to the project name created in Netbeans (i.e. Polish Table )

6) Edit project.properties file in nbproject directory. Change src.dir from src to 
source/src

7)Edit project.properties file in nbproject directory. Make sure that libs.classpath= property points to J2ME polish import client library. If not found, make sure that the following two lines are added:

8)file.reference.enough-j2mepolish-client.jar=C:/J2ME-Polish/import/enough-j2mepolish-client.jar 9.libs.classpath=${file.reference.enough-j2mepolish-client.jar}

Restart NetBeans IDE. From now on you can work completely using IDE. However you will need to compile from command line. Even this could be integrated - but didn't bother to figure out. Hopefully this should be sufficient to get you started.

Comment: Pavan: go to this link ..here all step are mention so follow this step ..[link](http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/documentation/installation.html)   hope its help. if any probs. let me know.

Comment: Hi,i have installed J2ME-Polish2.1.4 and netbeans j2me plugin ,after that i restared the ide,then i start creating j2me polish project,i eneterd project name and i clicked next button on ide,it is saying Unable to read selected devices - check your J2ME Polish installation. You will need at least J2ME Polish 2. ?                        Can i run j2me polish apps on Nokia Symbian Belle SdK 1.0 devices?

Comment: Pavan : alternative for me and those who cant make j2me polish work:


use LWUIT, it has more GUI features than polish. except making the final jar file super big, and throwing occational OutOfMemoryExceptions, the toolkit is really great, supporting gif animations, to 3d form transition animation, to combo boxed and lists ...this is really good ...more info visit [a LWUIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_User_Interface_Toolkit)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to the OP. For me, moving the jar file to a location where the path doesn't contain any spaces seemed to do the trick - or, put the jar in the root of your NB project folder and access it relatively.